# AngularJS Chaining Promises won't bind to template

Tags: angularjs, promise

I can't seem to figure to figure out why after using promises it still isn't waiting and so $scope.return_message is returning null.

```
function getRandomCommit()
    {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $scope.repos = Repos.query({username: 'octocat'}).$promise.then(function ( value )
        {
            var ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*value.length) + 1);
            $scope.repo = Repo.get({username: 'octocat'}, {repo: value[ranNum].name}).$promise.then(function ( value2 )
            {
                $scope.commits = Commit.query({username: 'octocat'}, {repo: value2.name}).$promise.then(function ( value3 )
                {
                    var ranNum2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*value3.length));
                    d.resolve(value3[ranNum2].commit.message);
                    return d.promise;
                });
            });
        });
    };
    $scope.return_message = getRandomCommit();`
```

Comment: what version of angular are you using? Templates no longer automatically unwrap promises in 1.2

Comment: ...I'm using 1.2.15...I'll look up unwrapping promises

Comment: Would I use $timeout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AngularJS 1.1.x and 1.0.x contained somewhat experimental feature called *unwrapping promises*. You could pass a promise to the template and once it got resolved, the template would automatically use the resolved value instead of the promise object itself.

Pretty cool, huh? It may sound like a nice feature but in fact it wasn't **that** useful after all. It added too much logic to AngularJS, slowed down evaluation and made code in templates/controllers unclear. AngularJS crew member commented on GitHub:

> This is a feature that didn't prove to be wildly useful or popular,
>   primarily because of the dichotomy between data access in templates
>   (accessed as raw values) and controller code (accessed as promises).
>
> In most code we ended up resolving promises manually in controllers
>   or automatically via routing and unifying the model access in this way.

Therefore it was [deprecated in AngularJS 1.2.x](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577).

### Your options now are:

- wait for the promise to resolve and set the variable on `$scope`
- force enabling unwrapping promises (deprecated in 1.2 and removed in 1.3 so it's not really an option anymore!)

To make your code work refactor `getRandomCommit` to return a promise:

```
function getRandomCommit () {
    var d = $q.defer();
    // your code ...
    return d.promise;
}
```

and change what `$scope.return_message` is:

```
getRandomCommit().then(resolved_value => {
    $scope.return_message = resolved_value;
});
```

If you're using AngularJS 1.2 you can still use promises unwrapping but note it's deprecated and removed in version 1.3. You can find more information in the [AngularJS 1.0->1.2 migration guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises).

### Edit (2014-10-30):

Recently AngularJS 1.3 was released. In this branch promises unwrapping is [**removed completely**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/fa6e411da26824a5bae55f37ce7dbb859653276d).

Comment: This answer is much better than the other one.

Comment: I think I'm almost there. I keep getting      
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`  
On this line:
    `getRandomCommit().then(function( resolved_value ) {`

Comment: According to angular-bangarang the return_message is a null promise

Comment: I had to remove my return statement outside the nest and it returned properly

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
function getRandomCommit() {
  var d = $q.defer();
  // do async tasks
  // call d.resolve(data) when finish
  return d.promise;
}

getRandomCommit().then(function (data) {
  $scope.return_message = data;
});
```

Comment: Do I need to pass then into the controller? Currently I'm getting `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`  in the console

Answer (score 0):

I no longer have an error in my console and bangarang can see the proper $scope.return_message thanks @miszy

`function getRandomCommit()
    {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $scope.repos = Repos.query({username: 'octocat'}).$promise.then(function ( value )
        {
            var ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*value.length) + 1);
            $scope.repo = Repo.get({username: 'octocat'}, {repo: value[ranNum].name}).$promise.then(function ( value2 )
            {
                $scope.commits = Commit.query({username: 'octocat'}, {repo: value2.name}).$promise.then(function ( value3 )
                {
                    var ranNum2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*value3.length));
                    d.resolve(value3[ranNum2].commit.message);
                    return d.promise;
                });
            });
        });
    };                   });
                });
            });
                        return d.promise;
        };
    getRandomCommit().then(function( resolved_value ) {
        $scope.return_message = resolved_value;
    });
}]);`

Comment: Now I'm just trying to get it to bind to the template.

Comment: This should be a new question, not an "answer" on your original question.